# Delete symbol right of cursor in vim

Tags: vim, editor, vi

There is `x` for deleting symbol under cursor in `vim` and `X` for deleting symbol left of cursor. I'd like to delete a symbol right of cursor. Of course, I can use `lxh` command. However, I'd prefer more convenient way. Is it possible?

Comment: your `lxh` won't work if your cursor was on the last char of a line. You need write some checking logic. apart from that,  assume `lxh` works, personally I don't see how in-convenient `lxh`  is...

Comment: I'd like something more standard and short. (I'm a novice in vim)

Comment: 1) there is no any built-in to do that. 2) you can write a perfect function to do that, but you have to create a mapping right? check your keyboard, in normal mode, which key is still free? would you assign this operation on `<Fx>` keys? if you made it 2 keystrokes, 1 key stroke shorter, how much would you win?